# Sklearn tf-idf TfidfVectorizer failed to capture one letter words

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, nlp, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

A particular instance is `"Queens Stop 'N' Swap"`. After transforming, I only got three features `['Queens', 'Stop', 'SWap']`. The `'N'` has been ignored. How can I capture the `'N'`?. All the parameters are default settings in my code.

```
### Create the vectorizer method
tfidf_vec = TfidfVectorizer()

### Transform the text into tf-iwine vectors
text_tfidf = tfidf_vec.fit_transform(title_text)
```

Comment: Are there other example words? Otherwise you could strip punctuation to have it handled as a word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not getting `'n'` as a token because it's not considered a token by default tokenizer:

```py
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

texts = ["Queens Stop 'N' Swap",]
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(token_pattern='(?u)\\b\\w\\w+\\b',)
tfidf.fit(texts)
tfidf.vocabulary_
{'queens': 0, 'stop': 1, 'swap': 2}
```

To capture 1 letter tokens, with capitalzation preserved, change it like:

```py
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(token_pattern='(?u)\\b\\w+\\b',lowercase=False)
tfidf.fit(texts)
tfidf.vocabulary_
{'Queens': 1, 'stop': 2, 'N': 0, 'swap': 3}
```

Comment: Should not `Queens` be captured as `Queens` instead of being `'queens'`, since you turn off the lowercase?

Comment: @NomardicRoku Yes, you're right, technical typo, corrected